# Vue Pinia store with rollback possibility

Tags: vue.js, state, pinia

Say, I have a list from persons in my application. That list will be populated from the state from a 'persons' object in my store. When I click on a person, I go to a 'detail' page from that person where I also can edit the person.

How can I achieve to do a rollback on a cancel of that screen? It seems like the object I'm editing in the details, is directly changing the state in the store. Can someone help me in the right direction about the 'temporary' state changes, till I click on save? Then I want to 'commit' it to the store, otherwise on a cancel, I want to rollback to the state it was before.

After the save, ofcourse the edited name or something, should be visible in the persons list directly. Anyone here to guide me with some examples of this scenario? I can't find good articles about things like rollbacks or things.

I've tried to set a loose object, and populate that from the store, but also that seems like a direct link to the store itself. I'm curious what's best practice with this case.

Comment: You can "accept" one of the answers by clicking the checkmark on the left of it to indicate that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the state of a pinia store with `$reset`: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#Resetting-the-state

If that is not precisely what you want, have a look at *plugins*: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/plugins.html
They let you define methods that will be usable on all stores, so this is where custom rollback-logic should go.

But maybe you should not think about how to do what you want with *one* store alone. You can have one store that represents what the user is currently entering (if you even need a store for that, might just do it in the component directly) and another that represents the state of things that were saved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I feel the same about just using the component to handle the edit, and then after saving, update the store. On cancel, just ignore the edited object and keep the store it was. I'm now using the clonedeep package from lodash. Is that something you mean?

Comment: @KentuckyMC that sounds like a very reasonable solution

Answer (score 0):

In Option Stores, you can reset the state to its initial value by calling the `$reset()` method on the store:

```
const store = useStore()
store.$reset()
```

Internally, this calls the `state()` function to create a new state object and replaces the current state with it.

In Setup Stores, you need to create your own `$reset()` method:

```
export const useCounterStore = defineStore('counter', () => {
  const count = ref(0)

  function $reset() {
    count.value = 0
  }

  return { count, $reset }
})
```

https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#Resetting-the-state

Comment: Yeah, the downside of this, is that on opening the page, there is a api call triggered that gets my information from the back-end. That state is stored in Pinia. So on resetting the whole store, I lost the information that I gathered already.